# WIX Condition не работает

Tags: wix

Условие не срабатывает. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться. Написала вот так

```
<Property Id="PRODUCT_V3_INSTALLED">
<ProductSearch Minimum="3.0.0" IncludeMinimum="yes" Maximum="4.0.0" IncludeMaximum="no" UpgradeCode="$(var.UpgradeCode)" />
</Property>

<Component Id="SchedulerService.exe.config" Guid="7FAA0D24-FA90-4DF1-8B94-83F257EDB7B3">
<Condition><![CDATA[NOT Installed OR NOT PRODUCT_V3_INSTALLED]]></Condition>
<File Id="SchedulerService.exe.config" Source="$(var.OpenSoft.InkRouter.SchedulerService.TargetDir)SchedulerService.exe.config" Name="SchedulerService.exe.config"/>
</Component>
```

Но данный файл не обновляется.

Comment: Хм. WIX — довольно редкая технология. А есть какие-нибудь warning'и?

Comment: Нет, ошибок нет, строит решение успешно

Comment: Ни ошибок, ни предупреждений нет. Если бы были - было бы хоть немного понятно, что не так.

Answer (score 1):

Файл может не обновляться по разным причинам. Может быть дело в файле(например, в версии) , а может и в в вашем условии. В любом случае, первая рекомендация - запустите установку из консоли командой

```
msiexec /i имя_msiки.msi /l*v file.log
```

Пройдите инсталляцию, в результате рядом с msi-кой появится файл `file.log` - это логи инсталляции. В этих логах поищите ваше условие, там будет написано, какое значение оно приняло - `True` или `False`. Если логи не наведут вас ни на какие мысли, то закидывайте их сюда, будем вместе смотреть.

Comment: А что не так с русским SO? По-моему вы все правильно сделали: раз у вопроса нет ответов, то нужно их добавить. Хотя, конечно, автор вопроса вряд ли уже добавит логи)